# validation of complete object graphs with hibernate annotation und spring

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have two classes

```
public class Person {
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Car {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Person driver;

    public Car(Person driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

I need to perform the validation of class Car in Spring Controller. When an error occurs on Person, the method `hasErrors()` returns not true but false. How can I perform the validation of Car (Car class contains a Person)?

Comment: you are already validating car(which contains person) object here,i don't understand your question here. could you be more specific??